# How to handle error occurred in partial view which is used in all the views in mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created one MVC 4 application. There are two Partial views.

1. Header
2. Footer

I have handled the errors in the application and when error comes, the application redirects the user to error page i.e. action - Index, Controller - Error and view - Index.

But the problem is this Error view is using the partial view - Header.

My problem is that the error is occurred in the partial view and this partial view is also used in **Error** view. So it causes the stack overflow exception. In this case if error comes, any view that is referencing the Header partial view is throwing the error.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> the application redirects the user to error page

I think the best you can do is to have plain old HTML page for this purpose. In my own project, I have simplified, minimalist-style HTML page with inner styles and single image.

Comment: But in my case, I have some processing on this partial view i.e. I am rendering the Menu from database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make several error pages? I have 1 error page for 400, another for 404 and so on.

You could have 1 error page for errors that occurs in your partial menu page.